I found issue with preventing of uploading images with text/number,by using tessaract package.The tesseract return some random text in plain image too


    const handleImageUpload = useCallback(async (event) => {
  
        const imageFile = event.target.files[0];     
        if (!imageFile) {
            return;
        }
     
            const result = await Tesseract.recognize(
                imageFile,
                'eng',  
            );
            const { data: { text } } = result;
            console.log(text)
       
    }, []);

  


export default OCR;


please someone correct the code . why some random text are there in the text extracted from the result of recognize method .
